# how to access double value using a float pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

how to access double value using a float pointer in C and return the value using a single statement?

lets say i have a float pointer

float *ptr;

and I wish to retrieve a double value with this using only a single statement. Now the issue is that the float pointer will be able to return 32 bit value in a single statment whereas I wish to return a 64 bit value. This is a conceptual question rather than a practical problem.

Thanks

Comment: `return *((double *)floatptr)`?

Comment: Please add some code to this. Also, cant you just cast the pointer? Why is it a float pointer?

Comment: You can't. A float pointer points to a float, not a double. You can get the float value and convert it to a double if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `return *ptr;`. If the return type of the function is `double`, the `float` value will automatically be converted to `double`.

If you are not immediately returning the value or assigning it to a `double` but want it converted to a `double` for additional arithmetic, you can do this with `(double) *ptr`. This expression first retrieves the `float` at `ptr` and then converts the value to a `double`.

If the value at `ptr` is a `float` value, there is no way to “retrieve a `double` value” from it. You cannot retrieve what is not there. You can only retrieve the `float` that is there and convert the value (after it is retrieved) to `double`.

If the value at `ptr` is a `double` value, then you should not be pointing to it with a pointer to `float`, so other parts of your code should be fixed to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Cast it.

```
ValueInPointer = *(double*)pfloat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `float*` called `ptr`, you can use.

```
*(double*)ptr;
```

Note that this will not produce meaningful results unless `ptr` really points to a `double`. Particularly, either `*(double*)ptr` or `*ptr` will not be meaningful.